# Type 'DateType' does not satisfy the constraint 'BasicDataNode error inside node_modules

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, antd, vite

I ma using Vite react with ts in my project.
I am having an issue in making the build because when I run yarn build this issue occurs and this is happening inside node_modules therefore I don't know how to resolve this.
i have reinstall the node_modules many time but not work.

this is the issue in the terminal

```
node_modules/rc-tree/lib/interface.d.ts:59:70 - error TS2344: Type 'DateType' does not satisfy the constraint 'BasicDataNode'.

59 export type KeyEntities<DateType = any> = Record<SafeKey, DataEntity<DateType>>;
                                                                        ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/rc-tree/lib/interface.d.ts:59:25
    59 export type KeyEntities<DateType = any> = Record<SafeKey, DataEntity<DateType>>;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This type parameter might need an `extends BasicDataNode` constraint.


Found 1 error in node_modules/rc-tree/lib/interface.d.ts:59

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "comet-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starter kit for comet web applications",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "https-preview": "serve dist"
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "antd": "^5.9.4",

    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "breakpoint-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "notistack": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-hotkeys-hook": "^3.4.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.21",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "https-localhost": "^4.7.1",
 
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "vite": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}": [
      "eslint --max-warnings=0"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter-kit",
    "vite"
  ]
}
```

here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",

    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

here is my tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", ]
}
```

here is my vite.congif.json file is

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    eslintPlugin({
      cache: false,
      include: ['./src/**/*.js', './src/**/*.jsx'],
      exclude: [],
    }),
    
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "./src/styles/_screens.scss";
        @import "./src/styles/_variables.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
  define: {
    global: 'global'
  },

});
```